# Server becomes unresponsive periodically, OOM Killer inactive?

Tags: ruby, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, out-of-memory

I'm hosting a Ruby application in a docker container on AWS. Unfortunately this Ruby application is known to leak memory so eventually it consumes all of the available memory.

I'm, perhaps naively, expecting OOM killer to get invoked and kill the Ruby process but nothing happens. Eventually the machine becomes unresponsive (web server doesn't respond, ssh is disabled). We force restart of the machine from the AWS console and get the following in the message the logs, so it is indeed alive at the time of the restart:

```
Apr 30 23:07:14 ip-10-0-10-24 init: serial (ttyS0) main process (2947) killed by TERM signal
```

I dont believe that this is resource exhaustion (ie running out of credits) in AWS. If I restart the application periodically the server never goes down.

- I'm not disabling OOM Killer or changing any of the [default docker memory config](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).
- I'm running a stock *Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03* kernel.
- This behavior is happening across multiple virtual instances in AWS

I'm very much at a loss here; why would memory pressure be causing machines to lock up?

Comment: Are you specifying the limit while running the containers? Also I assuming this is a EC2 instance with Docker on it and not ECS?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the solution I provided didn't seem to help the person who asked the question, but it might help someone else who stumbleupon here. The following are the 2 things I suggested which might be causing the problem.

**Suggestions 1**

*I am guessing you are using the offical ruby docker image and when you run the container ruby is running as `PID 1` inside the container.*

If ruby is running as `PID 1` then OOM killer wont be able to kill it, causing all the problem you are seeing.

To solve this problem you will have to make sure a proper `init` process runs as `PID 1`.

Docker 1.25 and above has the `--init` option for `docker run` command. This option will make sure that a proper `init` handles the tasks of `PID 1`, it will also pass all SIGNALs to your ruby application.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

> --init    API 1.25+ Run an init inside the container that forwards signals and reaps processes

The following is what docker uses as the `init`
https://github.com/krallin/tini

**Suggestion 2**

There is a known issue with Amazon Linux AMI the details can be found at the following link https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/794. As of writing I am not sure if the problem with AMI was fixed or not.

So try a different AMI as suggested in that thread say the Ubuntu AMI.

Comment: I'm using [passenger-full](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker), a base image created by Phusion. They have an underlying init system, so ruby processes are not PID 1.

Comment: @EightyEight Oh ok. In that case have you seen the following issue https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/794. It about a bug in amazon linux ami, you could try out Ubuntu if thats the case

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assuming that OOM will always target your Ruby application, but I don't think that is the case. You log line shows it killed you tty connection instead. I am betting it is killing other processes before your Ruby process and this is why your machine to seem un-responsive. You can read up on how OOM works and it might help here. I would look specifically at your oom_scores and see what you find there.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your comment Darrell. The event you refer to was triggered by the system reboot as far as I can tell, rather than OOM.

Comment: Right you are, my mistake. Do you know for sure that the ruby container is consuming all the memory before the host goes dark? This might be some other resource exhaustion issue. Can you get some process monitoring data for the next interval?

Comment: Darrell, what kind of information would be helpful? The application server spawns a set of ruby worker processes to handle web requests. Individual processes keep consuming more memory. I have a watchdog (monit) that kills the individual ruby processes when they reach a threshold (usually about 800 megs). That to me is a hint that memory consumption is the culprit. I don't see anything else out of the ordinary.

Comment: For quick and dirty, I would grab cpu and memory data and dump them to a file that, ideally, you can watch remotely. I would use a separate EFS share and create a cron'd or loop that ran this `uptime && free && (ps aux --sort -rss | head) && echo threads=$(ps -eLf | wc -l)` This should let you know if it is memory, threads, or just general load. Good luck